# Terence Tao Vol1 Proposition 8.2.6

Tags: real-analysis

I want to verify my proof towards part (c).

part (c):

If X = $X_1 \cup X_2$ for some disjoint $X_1$ and $X_2$, then $\Sigma_{x \in X_1} f(x)$ and $\Sigma_{x \in X_2} f(x)$ are absolutely convergent, and

$$\Sigma_{x \in X_1 \cup X_2} f(x) = \Sigma_{x \in X_1} f(x) + \Sigma_{x \in X_2} f(x)$$

Conversely, if $h : X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is such that $\Sigma_{x \in X_1} h(x)$ and $\Sigma_{x \in X_2} h(x)$ are absolutely convergent, then $\Sigma_{x \in X_1 \cup X_2} h(x)$ is also absolutely convergent, and $$\Sigma_{x \in X_1 \cup X_2} h(x) = \Sigma_{x \in X_1} h(x) + \Sigma_{x \in X_2} h(x)$$

Attempt:
$\Sigma_{x \in X : f(x) \neq 0} \implies f(x) = \Sigma_{x \in X_1 \cup X_2 : f(x) \neq 0}f(x)$. As we are working with disjoint sets whose union is X. Therefore we have the following equality:

$$f(x) = \Sigma_{x \in X_1 \cup X_2 : f(x) \neq 0}f(x) = \Sigma_{x \in X_1 : f(x) \neq 0} f(x) + \Sigma_{x \in X_2 : f(x) \neq 0} f(x)$$

Comment: The first statement seems incomplete. I think you are missing if $\sim_{X_1\cup X_2}f$ is absolutely convergent..

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention the absolute convergence part. Though is the rest ok ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you’re missing a hypothesis at the very beginning: for the forward direction, which is what you’re attempting to prove, you need to assume that $\sum_{x\in X}f(x)$ is absolutely convergent.

Next, the assertion that

$$f(x)=\sum_{\substack{x\in X_1\cup X_2\\f(x)\ne 0}}f(x)$$

makes no sense: the $x$ on the lefthand side is some specific element of $X$, while the $x$ on the righthand side is an index variable that has no fixed value. It’s like writing

$$n^2=\sum_{n=1}^3n^2\,:$$

the righthand side is an abbreviation for $1^2+2^2+3^2$, or $14$, while the lefthand side is just an algebraic expression with no definite value.

Now we come to the proof itself. You cannot simply **declare** that because $X$ is the disjoint union of $X_1$ and $X_2$, therefore

$$\sum_{x\in X}f(x)=\sum_{x\in X_1}f(x)+\sum_{x\in X_2}f(x)\,,$$

even with the added restriction that you consider only those $x$ such that $f(x)\ne 0$: that is precisely what you are supposed to **prove**, and you’ve offered no actual argument for it. You’ve also done nothing to show that $\sum_{x\in X_1}f(x)$ and $\sum_{x\in X_2}f(x)$ are absolutely convergent, and you’ll need that before you can prove that

$$\sum_{x\in X}f(x)=\sum_{x\in X_1}f(x)+\sum_{x\in X_2}f(x)\,.$$

To show that $\sum_{x\in X_1}f(x)$ is absolutely convergent, you have to show that

$$\sup\left\{\sum_{x\in A}|f(x)|:A\subseteq X_1\text{ and }A\text{ is finite}\right\}<\infty\,.$$

Fortunately, this is easy: each finite subset of $X_1$ is a finite subset of $X$, so

$$\begin{align*}
\sup&\left\{\sum_{x\in A}|f(x)|:A\subseteq X_1\text{ and }A\text{ is finite}\right\}\\
&\le\sup\left\{\sum_{x\in A}|f(x)|:A\subseteq X\text{ and }A\text{ is finite}\right\}\\
&<\infty\,,
\end{align*}$$

since $\sum_{x\in X}f(x)$ is absolutely convergent. A similar argument takes care of $\sum_{x\in X_2}f(x)$.

Once you have that out of the way, you can replace $X,X_1$, and $X_2$ by the countable sets

$$\begin{align*}
&X'=\{x\in X:f(x)\ne 0\}\,,\\
&X_1'=\{x\in X_1:f(x)\ne 0\}\,,\text{ and}\\
&X_2'=\{x\in X_2:f(x)\ne 0\}
\end{align*}$$

and observe that $X_1'\cap X_2'=\varnothing$ and $X'=X_1'\cup X_2'$. Now your goal is to prove that

$$\sum_{x\in X'}f(x)=\sum_{x\in X_1'}f(x)+\sum_{x\in X_2'}f(x)\,.$$

You can now use the countability of $X',X_1'$, and $X_2'$ to say that there are bijections $g:N\to X'$, $g_1:N_1\to X_1'$, and $g_2:N_2\to X_2'$, where each of $N,N_1$, and $N_2$ is either $\Bbb N$ or a set of the form $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ for some $n\in\Bbb N$, and rewrite the summations with numerical index variables. For instance, the first one becomes $\sum_{k=1}^\infty f\big(g(k)\big)$ if $N=\Bbb N$ and $\sum_{k=1}^nf\big(g(k)\big)$ if $N=\{1,\ldots,n\}$. From here on in I’ll assume for simplicity that $N=N_1=N_2=\Bbb N$; the other cases are no harder.

I don’t have the book in question, so I don’t know exactly what tools you have available at this point to finish the argument by showing that

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty f\big(g(k)\big)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty f\big(g_1(k)\big)+\sum_{k=1}^\infty f\big(g_2(k)\big)\,,$$

but I expect that you will have to look at limits of partial sums of these series.

Comment: Brian I never made that claim about f(x) = $\Sigma_{x \in X_1 \cup X_2 : f(x) \neq 0} f(x)$

Comment: @IWantToLearn: You most certainly did: look at the last displayed line at the very end of your question.

Comment: I understand. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: towards the end when you replace things by countable sets, then can you use the result on the countable sets and then mention as the result is true for countable sets; then, it must be true that we can split the sum? That is what you used towards the end of your proof right ?

Comment: Is it possible if you can complete? I am using this book for self-study. I will accept your answer. The summation on countable sets is done by replacing the index of the sum with bijection $f : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow X^{\prime}$  or $X$  as you mentioned.

Comment: @IWantToLearn: I really can’t take it any further, because I don’t know what results have already been proved at that point. If you’ve already proved that a countable absolutely convergent series can be split in this way, then you can simply apply that result; otherwise you’ll have to show that the limit of the partial sums $\sum_{k=1}^nf\big(g(k)\big)$ is equal to the sum of the limit of the partial sums $\sum_{k=1}^nf\big(g_1(k)\big)$ and the limit of the partial sums $\sum_{k=1}^nf\big(g_2(k)\big)$.

Comment: I understand. That is good. I will accept the answer.